# Inverse of strictly increasing function is continuous (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, monotone-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is strictly increasing, prove that $f^{-1}: f(\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Here is my attempt:

Let $a \in f(\mathbb R)$ be a limit point of $f(\mathbb R)$ and let $a_n$ be an increasing sequence with limit $a$, we want to show that $f^{-1}(a_n) \rightarrow f^{-1}(a)$.

(Lemma: $x < y$ implies $f^{-1}(x) < f^{-1}(y)$ .)

$f^{-1}(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence bounded above by $f^{-1}(a)$ so it has a limit $L$. If $L > f^{-1}(a)$ then there must be some $k$ such that $f^{-1}(a_k) > f^{-1}(a)$ but $a_k < a$, a contradiction. If $L < f^{-1}(a)$ then $f(L) < a$ so there is some $k$ such that $f(L) < a_k < a$, implying $L < f^{-1} (a_k)$, a contradiction. Therefore $L = f^{-1} (a)$.

So we have proven that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(a)$.

Using the same proof, if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f^{-1}(x)$ exists then it equals $f^{-1}(a)$.

Hence for any limit point $a$ of $f(\mathbb R)$ exactly one of the following holds:

1. $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(a)$ and there does not exist a decreasing sequence $a_n$ with limit $a$.
2. $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(a)$ and there does not exist an increasing sequence $a_n$ with limit $a$.
3. $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(a)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(a)$

So $f^{-1}: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: I am confused, how do (e.g.) $\lim_{x\to a^+}$ doesn't exists implies that it is continuous?

Comment: $lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}$ is a bad/incorrect way to put it. What I mean is there although $a$ is a limit point, there isn't a decreasing sequence with limit $a$. I will edit it.

Comment: I think it is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof looks correct, but I feel it is too convoluted. Here is how I would argue:

Let $y_0\in f(\Bbb R)$, say $y_0=f(x_0)$, and let $\epsilon>0$.

Let $y_-=f(x_0-\epsilon)$ and $y_+=f(x_0+\epsilon)$.

Let $\delta = \min\{y_0-y_-, y_+-y_0\}$, and note $\delta>0$.

Then for $z\in f(\Bbb R)$, if  $|z-y_0|<\delta$ then $y_-<z<y_+$ and hence
$$ f^{-1}(y_-)<f^{-1}(z)<f^{-1}(y_+), $$
i.e.
$$ x_0-\epsilon<f^{-1}(z)<x_0+\epsilon, $$
i.e.
$$ |f^{-1}(z)-f^{-1}(y_0)|<\epsilon$$
and we are done.

It probably helps to draw what's going on on a graph of $f$.